# Oracle APEX number format mask without comma

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to change the number eg. 1000 to 1.000, 10000 to 10.000 istead of 10,000 or 10,000.00

DO you have any idea? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's (unfortunately) no declarative way to modify thousands/decimal separators. Should be somewhere in "Edit application definition - Globalization" settings, but - there's nothing like that there.

So, do it yourself, manually. Navigate to shared components - security attributes - database session tab - initialization PL/SQL code and put this into it:

```
begin
  execute immediate q'[alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ', ']';
end;
```

which will set comma as decimal separator, and space as thousands (group) separator.

---

Example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ', ';

Session altered.

SQL> select 5000 val1,
  2         to_char(5000, '999G990D00') val2,
  3         to_char(5000, '999G990') val3
  4  from dual;

      VAL1 VAL2        VAL3
---------- ----------- --------
      5000    5 000,00    5 000

SQL>
```

Comment: Now, I am getting the numbers like 50 000 000,00  I want to get the 50.000.000

Comment: It depends on what you do (see an example in edited answer). You have to specify group and decimal characters in TO_CHAR call; if you don't, 5000 is just 5000 - no group separator, no decimal digits, nothing - just 5000.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(your_nr_col, '999G999G999G990', 'nls_numeric_characters='',.''') AS nr_formatted
  FROM t
```

if you're dealing with integers *only* ( without including any decimal separator ), put as much as **9**s to exceed the number of the digits while adding **G**s after each three padded digit starting from the right hand side.

If there might arise some cases in which the decimal separators are needed, then replace the second argument with **`'999G999G999G990D0000'`** to pad enough **0**s after single **D** character directing from left to right

<kbd>[DemO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d05c7336ccabf7b6f4191f6b324282bf)</kbd>